# prepopulate form with jquery and validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, form-processing

I am using the following code, to prepopulate entries for browsers that do not support html5 placeholder. I'm having 2 problems with it:

1) It only works for text boxes, not text areas... suggestions? 
2) I'm using the jquery validation plugin, and since the following code adds a value, the plugin thinks that there is something entered, and won't validate that field... Is there any way around this?

I need a way to still have effective validation, but be able to prepopulate the fields

```
$('input:text').each(
    function(){
        $(this)
            .val($(this).attr('placeholder'))
            .css('color','#999');
        $(this).click(
            function(){
                $(this)
                    .val('')
                    .css('color','#000');
            });
        $(this).blur(
            function(){
                if ($(this).val() === ''){
                    $(this)
                        .val($(this).attr('placeholder'))
                        .css('color','#999');
                }
            });
    });
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Include `textarea` in your selector.

#### Example

```
$('input[text], textarea')
```

2) On submit of the form, if the value in the input is equal to the [`defaultValue`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XUL/Property/defaultValue) property, set its value to blank (`''`).

#### Example

```
form.validate({
   submitHandler: function(form) {

       form.find('input[text], textarea').each(function() {
           if (this.defaultValue == this.value) {
               this.value = '';
           }
       });

       form.submit();
   }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Ad 1.)

```
$('input:text, textarea')
```

Should work.